# Onclick text appears next to the div instead of being under

Tags: javascript, html, events, text, onclick

I have a problem with my code I want the text that appears onclick to be under the main div but instead it appears next to it. Can someone have a clue of the mistake I made or the thing that I can add to my code to correct this ? I have also another question how can I add space between my div because I put a blue background but I didn't want to be like one block . Thank you

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .link{text-decoration:none; color:white;}

  .link:visited{color:white}

.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}

.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */
  
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}

div {font-family:'Varela Round';
}
  
  .opener {
  background-color: #07183d;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
}

.benefits {
  background-color: #07183d;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width:300px;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#upbutton {
  border: 1px dotted white;
}
</style>
<script>function show(id) { 
        if(document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display=='none') { 
            document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display='block'; 
        } 
        return false;
    } 
    function hide(id) { 
        if(document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display=='block') { 
            document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display='none'; 
        } 
        return false;
    }
</script>
<div class="row">
<div class="opener col"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick=" show('1');" class="link">SOCIETES: 400</a></div>

<div class="benefits" id="b1" style="display:none;">Part SBF 120 : 120<br />
Part Filiales +100M€: 280
<div id="upbutton"><a onclick=" hide('1');" >fermer</a></div>
</div>

<div class="opener col"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick=" show('2');" class="link" >CONTACTS: 25 400</a></div>

<div class="benefits col" id="b2" style="display:none;">Part CAC 40 : 15 700<br />
Part Filiales +100M€: 9 700<br />
% contacts IT: 21%
<div id="upbutton"><a onclick=" hide('2');">fermer</a></div>
</div>

<div class="opener col">EMAILS NOMINATIFS: 400</div>

<div class="opener col">OPT OUT: 3%</div>

  <div class="opener col">LIGNES DIRECTES: 35%</div></div>
```

Comment: Add display: inline-block; to the divs.

Answer (score 2):

just add the hidden divs in side the opener div it will appear under it, to add space between divs you can use border property for opener div, try the following code:

```html
<style type="text/css">
  .link{text-decoration:none; color:white;}

  .link:visited{color:white}

.row {
  display: flex; /* equal height of the children */
}

.col {
  flex: 1; /* additionally, equal width */
  
  padding: 1em;
  border: solid;
}

div {font-family:'Varela Round';
}
  
  .opener {
  background-color: #07183d;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-align: center;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  border: 1px white solid;
}

.benefits {
  background-color: #07183d;
  border: none;
  color: white;
  padding: 15px 32px;
  text-decoration: none;
  display: inline-block;
  font-size: 16px;
  width:300px;
}
</style>
<style type="text/css">}
a {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}
#upbutton {
  border: 1px dotted white;
}
</style>
<script>function show(id) { 
        if(document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display=='none') { 
            document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display='block'; 
        } 
        return false;
    } 
    function hide(id) { 
        if(document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display=='block') { 
            document.getElementById('b'+id).style.display='none'; 
        } 
        return false;
    }
</script>
<div class="row">
<div class="opener col"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick=" show('1');" class="link">SOCIETES: 400</a>

<div class="benefits" id="b1" style="display:none;">Part SBF 120 : 120<br />
Part Filiales +100M€: 280
<div id="upbutton"><a onclick=" hide('1');" >fermer</a></div>
</div>
</div>

<div class="opener col"><a href="#1" name="1" onclick=" show('2');" class="link" >CONTACTS: 25 400</a>

<div class="benefits col" id="b2" style="display:none;">Part CAC 40 : 15 700<br />
Part Filiales +100M€: 9 700<br />
% contacts IT: 21%
<div id="upbutton"><a onclick=" hide('2');">fermer</a></div>
</div>
</div>
<div class="opener col">EMAILS NOMINATIFS: 400</div>

<div class="opener col">OPT OUT: 3%</div>

  <div class="opener col">LIGNES DIRECTES: 35%</div></div>
```

Comment: Do you know how can I force this code so that when only one click can be open at a time ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean, can you provide more details?